# Sort ArraysList by name Android, Kotlin

Tags: android, sorting, kotlin, arraylist

I have a list like this:

`val list = ArrayList<Category> = ArrayList()`

Then, the `Category` class have

```
var name:String?=null
var amount:Float=0.0F
```

I have to sort this list by name, after sorting the sums of items of the same name must be in the added state. For example, I have list like this:

```
list.add(Category("apple", 100F))
list.add(Category("orange", 300F))
list.add(Category("banana", 400F))
list.add(Category("apple", 100F))
list.add(Category("banana", 300F))
list.add(Category("cherry", 100F))
```

After I've sort, it should like this:

```
apple 200F
banana 700F
orange 300F
cherry 100F
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group the categories by their `name`s, take the values, `reduce` them by an accumulation of their `amount`s and sort the result in the end.

See this:

```kotlin
data class Category(var name: String, var amount: Float)

fun main() {
    var list = mutableListOf<Category>()
    list.add(Category("apple", 100F))
    list.add(Category("orange", 300F))
    list.add(Category("banana", 400F))
    list.add(Category("apple", 100F))
    list.add(Category("banana", 300F))
    list.add(Category("cherry", 100F))
    // print the source list once in order to see differences in the output
    println(list)
                                            // group the items by name
    val sortedList: MutableList<Category> = 
        list.groupBy { it.name }
            // take the values
            .values
            // and map them
            .map {
                // by a reduction that
                it.reduce {
                    // accumulates the amounts of items with the same name
                    acc, item -> Category(item.name, acc.amount + item.amount)
                }
            // and finally sort the resulting list by name
            }.sortedWith(compareBy { it.name }).toMutableList()
    // print the result
    println(sortedList)
}
```

This outputs

```
[Category(name=apple, amount=100.0), Category(name=orange, amount=300.0), Category(name=banana, amount=400.0), Category(name=apple, amount=100.0), Category(name=banana, amount=300.0), Category(name=cherry, amount=100.0)]
[Category(name=apple, amount=200.0), Category(name=banana, amount=700.0), Category(name=cherry, amount=100.0), Category(name=orange, amount=300.0)]
```

in the Kotlin Playground.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sortBy()` method to first sort your list and then a loop to count amount

```kotlin
data class Category(val name: String, var amount: Int)

val list = mutableListOf<Category>()
list.add(Category("apple", 100))
list.add(Category("orange", 300))
list.add(Category("banana", 400))
list.add(Category("apple", 100))
list.add(Category("banana", 300))

list.sortBy { it.name }

val result = mutableListOf<Category>()
var category = Category(list[0].name, 0)
for(item in list) {
    if (item.name == category.name) {
        category.amount += item.amount
    } else {
        result.add(category)
        category = item
    }
}
result.add(category)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in a few lines:

```
val sortedMap = list.groupBy { it.name }
            .mapValues { entry -> entry.value.map { it.amount }.sum() }
            .toSortedMap()
```

First, you group by category name. Then you map the list of values by adding them and finally sort the map.